# Firebase DebugView doesn't get parameter

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I want to log event `level_up` with two parameters: `level` and `character` from Unity.
To check events I use DebugView in Firebase. And when I log event with parameters I can see it in DebugView without parameter `level`.

To log I call method `LogEvent` from `FirebaseAnalytics` class:

```
Parameter[] Parameters = {
    new Parameter("level", 12),
    new Parameter("character", "Superman"),
};
FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("level_up", Parameters);
```

To check logging events I call it in a console:

```
adb logcat -s "FA", "FA-SVC"
```

And see:
[logcat console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MLTY.png), but there isn't the `level` parameter in DebugView, but is the `character`:
[DebugView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONs9f.png)
I expecting that there will be the `level` in DebugView when I log event with `level` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though level *is included* in the output.

Note that there are some other parameters included in the mix but your "level" and "character" parameters are there.

[image]